# Laravel - Multiple Production Environments

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

We have a Laravel 4.2 site based in the US that we're looking to whitelabel in Canada then the UK. I have a local and test environment for both (staging vs canada_staging, etc), and the problem I have with production is we have a lot of if conditions that checks if the environment is production (`if (App::environment() === 'production')` for instance). I could use `production` for both, but each site has its own specific configuration and language files (for instance they have provinces instead of states). Is there an easy way to overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create file `app/bootstrap/environment.php` on each server and define env.:

```
<?php

return 'production-us;
```

In `app/bootstrap/start.php` in detect env. section add this:

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function ()
{
    return require __DIR__.'/environment.php';
});
```

You will have unique env. on each server in the easiest way.

Related post [here](http://crynobone.com/posts/5/alternative-environment-detection-for-laravel-4).